# How can I send some commands to another android device from my android phone?

Tags: android, connection, command, google-cloud-messaging

I'd like to send some simply commands, like a led flashing, from my android phone to another android phone, by internet connection (3G) not wifi...
How can I do?
I have a apache server if it needs...

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to use Push Notifications for this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Answer (score 0):

I`m not expert but perhaps you can use the apache server like a blackboard, via php/mysql; your phone writes commands over a table of a database and the other device reads is through a running service. The table is used as a FIFO pool.

Another way, more complex perhaps is using push notifications with GCM.